# How can I disable string/text suggestions in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

**How to disable these string suggestions in VS Code (in the red square) for JavaScript?**

[image]

Comment: Ideally you would actually provide a [mre]. Show code and instructions to reproduce the kind of information you're showing in a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

```
"javascript.suggest.names": false
```

Comment: It seems that the screenshot shows that this concerns JS, I'm sorry that I didn't explicitly point it out, but I see that they answered and how to get rid of it on js and on other files, what's wrong with that?

Comment: oh I didn't see that this was a self-answer. When you self-answer, the question and answer are both expected to meet quality standards (see [ask] and [answer]). That includes including enough info in the question to understand the question. If you don't say it's specifically about JS suggestions based on names of other variables/functions/etc in your question, and then you give an answer that's only for JS, and only for suggestions based on names of other variables/functions/etc., then you aren't correctly answering your own question.